# java.net.SocketTimeOutException: Operation timed out (name2addr) root cause

Tags: java, web-services, network-programming

Mobile client(using a SIM card) is trying to send data to web server. During that we are getting **java.net.SocketTimeOutException: Operation timed out (name2addr)**. Is it because of the network provider or because of the server?

Comment: connection is talking much longer time to connect your web server. please post your code to get more help.

Comment: Question is a bit vague as it could be because of the network provider or the server. Please paste the full error stack trace.